# Are there class-independent methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

In the first chapter of *Eloquent Ruby*, Russ Olsen writes:

> The `Float` method turns its argument—usually a string—into a floating point number.

Ruby newbie I had been under the impression that Ruby methods belong to classes by definition, so that for example `Fixnum` and `Array` each have their own separate `:is_a?` (presumably including a greater or lesser amount of shared code), but "usually a string" implies that `Float` is a single method can be called on objects of different classes. Can someone please clarify the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Float` is both a class and a [method in `Kernel`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-Float). The `Kernel` module is included in all Ruby objects by default, meaning that you can call the `Float` method from **anywhere**.

The `Float` method will work with arguments that are either a `Float`, `Fixnum`, `String`, or any other object that has the `to_f` method (this method has to return a `Float`):

```
class Foo
   def to_f
     42.0
   end
end
Float Foo.new # => 42.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

"or any other object that has the to_f method" -- because `Float` is a different method that depends on `to_f`, or because it's an alias of `to_f`?

Comment: @hjkml The `Float` method checks the type of the argument in this order: Fixnum -> Float -> Bignum -> Nil (errors) -> attempts to call `to_f`.

Comment: Thanks. So then getting back to the core of my original question, does each Ruby class have its own `to_f` method? To what degree is there code shared between different classes' version of the method?

Comment: @hjkml No, each Ruby class does not have a `to_f` method. Only methods in `Object`, `BasicObject`, and `Kernel` are present in all classes. The `to_f` methods are implemented very differently in `Fixnum` and `String` for instance, due to the nature of the conversion needed to produce a `Float`.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I meant "each class on which it's possible to call `.to_f`." Last question, and thanks very much again for your help and patience: does the implementation of `to_f` for `Fixnum` and `String` share any code at all?

Comment: @hjkml Not really, [this is the `String#to_f` implementation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3614f8bd1c813916054079055d13462e90808a96/string.c#L4816-L4820) (which relies on [`rb_cstr_to_dbl`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/5363dce93848410097471355cd578d1e68fa2c93/object.c#L2804-L2886)), and [this is the `Fixnum#to_f` implementation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/5363dce93848410097471355cd578d1e68fa2c93/numeric.c#L3635-L3643)